# Method to encrypt an image and save it in Gallery in React Native for iOS platform?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

I need to encrypt an image and save the encrypted file in Gallery. Is it possible on iOS platform? Using React Native (JS) and OpenSSL for encryption.

Any guide will be helpful!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. You can manage your app's separate gallery to manipulate such data. But native option doesn't allow it. Also, check how OpenSSL can be used with React Native for iOS.

Comment: But there is a way I guess where we can convert the image (encrypted file) in PNG form and save it. iOS gallery will not detect anything else.